# showing that a function is not uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis

So I was given a problem that states: Show whether or not the function is continuous.

I chose to show that my given function is not uniformly continuous via Cauchy preservation. The function given is $f(x)=1/x^2$. Can I show that if I chose a sequence like $x_n=1/n$ and since I can show that for some $\delta$, there exists N that belongs to $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all n,m greater than or equal to N, $\lvert x_n-x_m\rvert<\delta$ for this sequence, then I can extend this to $\lvert f(x_n)-f(x_m)\rvert$<$\epsilon$. And for my function if we substitute $x$ for $1/n$ then my sequence $1/n$ becomes mapped to a sequence that is not Cauchy, therefore, it shows that this sequence is not uniformly continuous.

This by no means as formal as I will write it but what confused me is the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous but using a sequence that is convergent and follows Cauchy Criterion like the one used above to substitute into the function still be Cauchy?

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the statement carefully.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ preserves Cauchy sequences.

The contrapositive of this is: if $f$ does not preserve Cauchy sequences, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

The second statement tells you nothing about functions that *do* preserve Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. That makes so much sense